# Select problems in IE9 - in other browsers it works perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have problems with this particular form, i need first to select a value and then to submit the form. Submit form works good, however the default selection value in all browsers is selected and it is Acceptable, except in IE where no default selection value is selected. In IE there is nothing selected by default.

How do I fix this?

Picture of the problem  :
[image: the selection form]

:

```html
  <select name="formQuality" id="formQuality"  value="acceptable">
  <option  value="acceptable">Acceptable</option> 
  <option  value="good">Good</option>
  <option     value="better">Better</option>
  <option    value="excellent">Excellent</option>
  <option    value="best">Best</option>
  </select>
```

```html
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted
$input = $_POST['inputText']; //get input text
$varQuality = $_POST['formQuality'];
$message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}    
?>

<br>   
<form action="" method="post">
  <h1>Choose Quality:</h1>
  
  <?php 
      $thequa = htmlspecialchars($_POST['formQuality']);        
  ?>
  
  <select name="formQuality" id="formQuality"  value="<?php echo $thequa;?>">
  <option <?php if ($thequa1 == 'acceptable') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?> value="acceptable">Acceptable</option>
  <option selected="true" value="acceptable">Acceptable</option>  
  <option <?php if ($_POST['formQuality'] == 'good') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?> value="good">Good</option>
  <option  <?php if ($_POST['formQuality'] == 'better') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>   value="better">Better</option>
  <option  <?php if ($_POST['formQuality'] == 'excelent') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>  value="excellent">Excellent</option>
  <option  <?php if ($_POST['formQuality'] == 'best') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>  value="best">Best</option>
  </select> 
 
  <textarea name="inputText" cols="100" rows="20" style="border:solid 1px orange;"><?php echo $thetext;?></textarea> 
  <p>
  <input type="submit" value="Rewrite" name="SubmitButton"/>
 
</form>
```

Comment: If you have a question about browsers, it's far better to post the actual markup that the browser gets, rather than the server code that generates it. The *selected* attribute is boolean, it does not require a value. In XHTML it is given the value "selected", but only to satisfy the requirements of XML, not because it's actually necessary.

Comment: Ok, I did so and it works good on the stackoverflow's test bit not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The intended way to preselect an option is setting the `selected` attribute on the option element, rather than adding a `value` attribute to the select field.

```html
<select name="formQuality" id="formQuality">
<option value="acceptable" selected>Acceptable</option> 
<option value="good">Good</option>
<option value="better">Better</option>
<option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
<option value="best">Best</option>
</select>
```

This produces the expected result in all browsers, including IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use selected="selected" 
Like,

```
<option value="My Default" selected="selected">
```

to make an option as default selected value. This works in all browsers.